# When does $\lim_{t\to \infty}f(x+t)-f(t)$ not exist?

Tags: limits

I'm reading a proof where it's proven that $\lim_{t\to\infty}f(t)/t$ exists and let's say it's some $a$. Later the author remarks that $\lim_{t\to \infty}f(x+t)-f(t)$ may not exist. Shouldn't this be equal to $ax$? I'm not quite getting the nuance here.

Comment: Consider $f(x)=\sin x$.

Comment: What happens if you consider $f(x)=x+\sin x$? The point is that, average cannot control its sub-linear deviation.